# Force no line-break on pseudo element (:after)

Tags: javascript, css

http://codepen.io/ethanclevenger91/pen/vNjOyP

EDIT: This CodePen now showcases the variety of proposed solutions

If you resize the available space in this pen, you'll see that in the top heading, you eventually reach a point where the diamond (created via a pseudo-element) will line-break, but the last word does not, so the pseudo-element is on its own line.

I'd like to fashion a solution using pure CSS that behaves like the second heading, where the last word breaks if the pseudo-element breaks. Currently I've implemented it via Javascript, as the content of the headings will come from a database.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="alpha">A heading that takes up nearly the entire width</h1>
<h1 class="alpha solution1">A solution that would require Javascript</h1>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
$brand-primary:lightblue;
$brand-secondary:darken(lightblue, 40%);
@mixin hidpi($ratio) {
  @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: $ratio), (min-resolution: #{round($ratio*96)}dpi) {
      @content;
  }
}
body {
  position:relative;
  height:100vh;
  background:$brand-primary;
  width:100%;
}
.container {
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  position:relative;
}
.alpha {
  text-align:center;
  color:$brand-secondary;
  &:not(.solution1) {
    &:after {
      content:'';
      @extend %diamond;
      margin-left:11px;
    }
  }
  &.solution1 {
    .diamond {
      @extend %diamond;
      margin-left:11px;
    }
  }
}
%diamond {
  width:13px;
  height:14px;
  display:inline-block;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  border:1px solid $brand-secondary;
  vertical-align:middle;
  @include hidpi(2) {
    height:13px;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var content = $('.solution1').html();
  var lastChar = content.slice(-1);
  $('.solution1').html(content.slice(0, -1)+'<span style="white-space:nowrap">'+lastChar+'<span class="diamond"></span></span>');
});
```

Comment: adding more markup would be a valid answer?

Comment: _"If you resize the available space in this pen, you'll see that in the top heading, you eventually reach a point where the diamond (created via a pseudo-element) will line-break,"_ Difficult to reproduce resize line-break at codepen window. Though tried removing `vertical-align:middle` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also go with using the standard diamond from UTF8: `◇`.

If you let your `:after` as `display: inline` it will not break because you're not adding any space between the last word and it.

```css
.alpha.solution3:after {
  display: inline;
  content: "◇";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="alpha solution3">A solution that does not require Javascript neither a SPAN</h1>
```

If this character is too bold for you, you can make your own font, use `font-face` and go with it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoxjzO

This will also work on browsers which do not support `transform`.

Comment: I'd still have to add that `<span>` via JS unless I were to parse the string when the PHP outputs it, since the content is coming from a DB.

Comment: yes, just saw that was the approach you did using JS, sorry

Comment: Budget is running short, or I'd go the font route. So bookmarked as a "nice to have", and in my opinion, the best answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you change the display to `inline`, you can no longer animate the `:after` via CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to prevent line breaks in the `h1`, and wrap the text in a `span` element where you restore the normal behavior.

```css
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 > span {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Additionally, Chrome also needs

```css
h1 > span::after {
  content: '';
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: relative;
}
.alpha {
  text-align: center;
  color: #2e7e99;
}
.alpha:after {
  content: '';
  width: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  border: 1px solid #2e7e99;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 11px;
}
h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
h1 > span {
  white-space: normal;
}
h1 > span::after {
  content: '';
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1 class="alpha">
        <span>A heading with a decorative pseudo-element that breaks by itself</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't resize to test with your snippet, but if I drop that into my pen, it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Whoops, you ninja-edited your answer. This works, and I had considered it. The markup is gross, but it's probably a better idea than JS.

Comment: @EthanC I didn't expect my first code to work, but it seemed to do so when I tested it at first. But it doesn't, so I fixed by changing the html.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure this answer works. Your snippet still has the decoration line-break by itself if I resize the window.

Comment: @EthanC Oh, I see. It worked well on Firefox, but not on Chrome. Fixed.

Comment: There it is. Not ideal, but it'll do. I'll be surprised if anyone comes up with something that doesn't need adjusted markup.

Comment: In 2022, this works for me in Firefox (ver. 101), but not Chrome (ver. 103).